# How do I set the Rain Bird ST-8 2.0 to work with an indexing valve

Tags: valve, irrigation

Equipment:

Timer: Rain Bird ST-8 2.0
Indexing Valve: K Rain 4000 4 zone

I recently had a new irrigation timer installed, the unit I purchased required the use of a pump relay due to the voltage requirements.

The system is connected and starts the sprinklers.

I've set up the zones and now I'm trying to start a specific zone. When selecting the zone the valve will only start the next zone in the index not the selected zone.

For example: I ask for zone 3 but zone 1 starts, try again and zone 2 starts.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: fix the miswiring

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior.

The manufacturer's [Indexing Valve Instruction Guide](https://www.krain.com//content/files/images/LandingPages/Indexing%20Valves/4000%20Series/4000%20Series%20Indexing%20Valve%20Instruction%20Guide.pdf), at Page 1 of 6 in describing the cam that distributes the water flow, says this:

> [The cam is] Used to index the valve to the **next zone** and controls how many outlets are to be used.

The words "next zone" are telling. The user sets the cam to a specific zone, and then when water is supplied, the indexing valve rotates one place and provides water to the *subsequent* zone.

If you want to start with zone 1, you must set the cam to the last zone before turning on the water.